# Problems with Text Formatting CrystalReports

Tags: javascript, html, .net

When I Copy&Paste a text from a CrystalReports viewer to a TextBox, somethings appears especial simbols when save it to DB.

Example:
[(1) Crystal Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4AEl.png)

[(2) DataBase - Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMWgP.png)

Someone has this or similar problem?

Comment: CrystalReports may have it's own Wysiwyg editor, which format the text you're typing.
Di you try to insert the text into a code editor like `Notepad` to see if you have any special characters?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, I've tried pasting text into notepad and sublime, but none special characters appears

Comment: I'm Not founded a solution, So finally I've added a Trigger on Data Base, to clean those characters when Saves.

Comment: Glad to head, could you add your solution as response and make it as valid ? 
It may helps others. Cheers